# Javascript: innerHTML causing NaN return value

Tags: javascript

Why is NaN being returned after using `innerHTML`?

The issue I'm running into specifically affects `this.draggedElement.position()` directly after appending HTML through innerHTML. Researching, I realize that innerHTML recreates that section of the DOM and all DOM bindings are invalid. However, it seems as though the only function that is affected is `this.draggedElement.position()`.

Console logging, for example, `this.draggedElement.styles()` or `this.draggedElement.node` returns the same results before and after the innerHTML call. However, `this.draggedElement.position()` returns `{"top": 0, "left": 0, "height": NaN, "width": NaN}`. Any idea what is causing this? Thank you!

EDIT: Screenshot from 3 `console.logs` inside the `position` function:

[image]

**Canvas.js File**

```
class Canvas {
  constructor({ window, document, node, spacingX = 20, spacingY = 80 }) {
    this.node = node;
    this.blocks = [];
    this.grabbedNode = null;
    this.draggedElement = null;
  }

  position = () => {
    const { top, left } = this.node.getBoundingClientRect();

  //EDIT: Screenshot from the below 3 console.logs https://snipboard.io/FyLSgZ.jpg

  //console.log(this.node.getBoundingClientRect());
  //console.log(this.draggedElement.node);
  //console.log(this.draggedElement.position());


    return {
      top: top + this.window.scrollY,
      left: left + this.window.scrollX,
      scrollTop: this.node.scrollTop,
      scrollLeft: this.node.scrollLeft,
    };
  };

  appendHtml = (html) => {
  
    //Example console.log(this.draggedElement.position()) output: {"top": 365, "left": 524, "height": 119,"width": 318}
    //This line right here messes up the this.draggedElement.position() element
    
    if (html !== undefined) {
      this.node.innerHTML += html;
    }

   //Example console.log output: {"top": 0, "left": 0, "height": NaN, "width": NaN}

    return this.node.innerHTML;
  };


  grab = (grabbedNode) => {
    const { mouseX, mouseY } = this.state;
    const draggedElement = grabbedNode.cloneNode(true);
    const id = this.nextBlockID();

    draggedElement.classList.remove("create-flowy");
    draggedElement.innerHTML += `<input type='hidden' name='blockid' class='blockid' value='${id}'>`;

    this.document.body.appendChild(draggedElement);

    this.grabbedNode = grabbedNode;

    this.registerDragger(draggedElement);

    const { dragX, dragY } = this.setState({
      dragX: mouseX - grabbedNode.offsetLeft,
      dragY: mouseY - grabbedNode.offsetTop,
    });

    this.draggedElement.styles({
      left: mouseX - dragX + "px",
      top: mouseY - dragY + "px",
    });

    this.toggleDragger(true);

    return draggedElement;
  };
}

export default Canvas;
```

**Index.js**

```
function snap(block) {
    const { draggedElement } = canvas;

    if (!canvas.isRearranging) {
      canvas.appendChild(draggedElement.node);
    }

    const { top, left, scrollTop, scrollLeft } = canvas.position();

    canvas.draggedElement.styles({
      left: block.x - totalWidth / 2 + totalRemove - left + scrollLeft + "px",
      top: block.y + block.height / 2 + canvas.spacingY - top + "px",
    });


    if (arrowX < 0) {

      //This append is causing issues with the draggedElement.position() portion (x and width NAN)
      canvas.appendHtml(`
        <div class="arrowblock">
          <input type="hidden" class="arrowid" value="${draggedElement.id}">
          <svg preserveaspectratio="none" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="
              M 20 0
              L 20 ${canvas.spacingY / 2}
              L ${arrowX} ${canvas.spacingY / 2}
              L ${arrowX} ${arrowY}" stroke="#C5CCD0" stroke-width="2px"/>
            <path d="
              M ${arrowX - 5} ${arrowY - 5}
              H ${arrowX + 5}
              L ${arrowX} ${arrowY}
              L ${arrowX - 5} ${arrowY - 5}
              Z" fill="#C5CCD0"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      `);
    }

    checkOffset();
  }
```

**checkOffset()**

```
function checkOffset() {

    //console.log(canvas.draggedElement.position());
    //output: {"top": 0, "left": 0, "height": NaN, "width": NaN}
    

      canvas.blocks.forEach((block) => {
        const blockElement = canvas.findBlockElement(block.id);

        block.x =
          blockElement.position().left +
          (canvas.position().left + canvas.position().scrollLeft)
          
          //Issues are caused because of return value for canvas.draggedElement.position()
          - canvas.draggedElement.position().width / 2 -
          40;

      });

    }
  }
```

Comment: The object returned by `canvas.draggedElement.position()` does not return a value with a key `width` or `height`. Only `left`, `top`, `scrollLeft`, and `scrollTop` are keys.

Comment: @Rojo Thank you for the reply! That definitley makes sense. Would that also cause `top` and `left` to get reset to 0? Before: `{"top": 365, "left": 524, "height": 119,"width": 318}` after `{"top": 0, "left": 0, "height": NaN, "width": NaN}`